# Extract columns from a file and performing function on others

Tags: awk

I have a file with 6 columns of data. I want to make a new text file which only contains 2 of the columns but I want one of the new columns to be multiplied by a variable (which I will input). I would also like an additional column which just numbers the rows.

eg input

```
00001file 3.0 3.2 0.001 4.0 7

00002file 2.0 6.9 0.003 9.7 10

00003file 2.3 3.4 0.004 4.5 15
```

eg output (column1 - row number, column2 - original column6, column3 - original column2 * 10)

ie

```
1 7 30

2 10 20

3 15 23
```

I hope that makes more sense.
Thanks
Sonya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
awk '{print NR" "$NF" "$2*10}' input.file
1 7 30
2 10 20
3 15 23
```

Comment: Brilliant, that did the trick, thanks!